# AC signal combination

Tags: ac, audio, conversion, stereo

I have a question about combining two AC signals into one.

For my project I need to convert stereo audio to mono audio.

For the conversion I used this circuit:

[image: stereo to mono conversion]

I made this simple circuit on my breadboard to try out if this will work. I didn't use the audio connector instead I connected the measurement leads directly to the resistors. I hooked my signal generator to it, I hooked my oscilloscope to the circuit and configured some easy sine waves.

FG channel 1 configuration:

[image: FG channel 1 configuration]

FG channel 2 configuration:

[image: FG channel 2 configuration:]

FG channels measured seperatly on oscilloscope:

[image: FG channels measured seperatly on oscilloscope]

I know that if you combine 2 sine waves together that you will simply get the sum of the 2 sine waves. Why is it then that my 2 sine waves didn't get summed up together? I expected that the output waveform would have a peak-to-peak voltage of 8V. Yes, I know this is exactly what you want if you convert stereo to mono but I wonder why this happens.

Combined signals measured after the 2 resistors:

[image: Combined signals measured after the 2 resistors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That passive component technique of mixing the two inputs will effectively output the average of the two inputs that is to say at any instant in time the output will be (V1 + V2)/2.

If both the inputs are at the same voltage then the output will also be at that voltage, the average of the two inputs has been output.

Looking at it in another way, the two resistors form a potential divider, the output of which is mid-way between the inputs, so if V1=5V and V2=3V, the output will be half way between which is 4V which is also the average of the two inputs, (5+3)/2 =4.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation. It's really helpfull!

Comment: @RandyPeeters Thanks for the acknowledgement. The concept I described above can be extended to any number of inputs. For example, take a 5 input resistive mixer, the instantaneous output will still be the average of the 5 instantaneous inputs. So Vout = (V1+V2+V3+V4+V5)/5. You can prove this to yourself if you want to by applying 5 different dc voltages to the 5 inputs of a 5-input resistive mixer and using either Superposition Theorum or Millman's theorum to find the output voltage which will be the average of the 5 inputs. For this to work the resistors must all be equal value.

Comment: Wow James that's amazing!!! You're very helpfull!!!

Answer (score 1):

> *Why is it then that my 2 sine waves didn't get summed up together?*

Consider this: if both of your input signals were identical (say 1 kHz and 4 volts p-p), you could instead use one common input signal feeding both resistors. Then, on the output, would you expect a sinewave that is 8 volts p-p? Can you realistically expect that two parallel resistors can produce any circuit gain?